# ¿Cómo pasar archivos desde Linux a partición de Windows?

Tags: linux

Quiero pasar algunos archivos de `Linux` a la `partición` en donde tengo `Windows`, pero cuando abro el `explorador de archivos` e intento `copiar y pegar` a la ubicación de la partición de `Windows` no aparece la opción de `Pegar` en esta, en cambio, sí me permite pasar archivos de la `partición de windows` a `linux`.

Lo que hice fue cambiar los permisos al `/dev/sda2` con `chmod 775`, pero sigue igual, no puedo pasar archivos a esta partición.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia, `/dev/sda2` es la partición de `Windows` y el de `Equipo` obviamente el de `linux`.

Me gustaría saber cómo compartir archivos de forma `gráfica` y por `terminal` entre los `sda´s`. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿ Como tienes montada la partición ? Haz `mount | fgrep sda2` y añadelo a la pregunta.

Comment: /dev/sda2 on /run/media/chris/BEC6DED0C6DE87D3 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: Este es lo que me mostró con ese comando @Trauma

Comment: El problema lo tienes con los permisos NTFS, si dejas un subdirectorio dentro del sda2 con permisos de escritura a everyone seguro que puedes escribir dentro desde linux. Si no pudieras echa un vistazo a este link que lo explica paso a paso https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1586804

Comment: También puede ocurrir que en Windows se tenga habilitado el "Inicio Rápido" (una hibernación camuflada). Esto impediría que la escritura en la partición Windows. La forma más rápida y sencilla de deshabilitarlo es iniciar Windows, abrir la consola (símbolo del sistema como admin) y ejecutar `powercfg -h off` . Si ése era el error, desde Linux se podría escribir en esa partición.